# Aware DateTime object not adapting to change in DST

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I wrote a generator in python that yields a new day of data at each call from a pandas DataFrame. My DataFrame is unix timestamp indexed. My first attempt at a code worked as follows (df is the dataframe, tz is a pytz.timezone (Europe/Amsterdam in my case):

```
def interval_generator(df, tz):
    today = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(df.index.min(), tz)
    last_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(df.index.max(), tz)
    while today <= last_day:
            tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            yield df.loc[tz.localize(today).timestamp():tz.localize(tomorrow).timestamp() - 1]
            today = tomorrow
```

However when running my code I noticed that the DateTime object has the weird behaviour of really sticking with the timezone it was initially attached to (especially the incremented hour). Example of the (in my eyes) weird behaviour:

```
 import datetime
 import pytz
 tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
 # This is when daylight saving times stops in the Netherlands in 2015.
 t1 = datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 25, 0, 0)
 t2 = t1 + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
 t1_localized = tz.localize(t1)
 t2_localized = tz.localize(t2) 
 t2_loc_incremented = t1_localized + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

When printing the output of these final three variables you get:

```
>>> t1_localized
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 25, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
>>> t2_localized
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
>>> t2_loc_incremented
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Amsterdam' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

More importantly for my code, the timestamp for both versions of t2 is different:

```
>>> t2_localized.timestamp()
1445814000.0
>>> t2_loc_incremented.timestamp()
1445810400.0
```

I solved this in my generator function with the following workaround:

```
def interval_generator(df, tz):
    today = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(df.index.min(), tz=tz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    today = datetime.datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%m-%d')
    last_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(df.index.max(), tz=tz).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    last_day = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_day, '%Y-%m-%d')
    while today <= last_day:
            tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            yield df.loc[tz.localize(today).timestamp():tz.localize(tomorrow).timestamp() - 1]
            today = tomorrow
```

Which basically gets me the desired functionality, but I can't help but wonder whether there isn't a better way to deal with this issue. Is there any good alternative for my problem? Is this considered a bug of the datetime module? (I am using python 3.4) I tried googling, but could not find anything

Comment: pandas has extensive timezone handling capability. you should just use ``Timestamp`` as all of these things just work. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-zone-handling

Comment: @Jeff Thanks, I'll take a look and see if I can refactor my code using the standard pandas methods.